# Suitable English word for "Ghairat"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for a male being Conscious/Emotional about his family's chastity (his women in particular)? I have tried to find a lot, but no single word was suitable enough to translate it. Is there any?

Comment: Depends on the sense of the term you're looking for.  "Prudish" is the first that comes to mind, but that has a negative flavor to it.

Comment: Prudish is too much. Some lighter word?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about translating.

Comment: Is this your question, in full: *What is a word meaning being conscious or emotional or possessive about your chastity, particularly as applied to a woman?* If so, rephrase it that way. If not, then you are asking people to aim for a target that is unknown, at least to English speakers who do not speak Urdu.

Comment: I have tried to give original words reference as there would be some Urdu/Hindi/Persian users as well. Anyways updated it

Comment: Protective?....

Comment: @Christopher I think possessive word was unnecessary. It is more about being Conscious/Emotional than vulnerable

Comment: Perhaps "having self respect" is a term that might fit, though it doesn't strongly imply chastity.

Comment: This is a cultural concept that doesn't really exist in Anglophone societies; consequently words for it don't exist in English.

Comment: It is "family honor" applied in a context-sensitive (perhaps perverted) meaning. See also: UNWomen  http://www.endvawnow.org/en/articles/731-defining-honourcrimes-and-honour-killings.html

Comment: O.L.D. Online: "The family honour is at stake." ( *honour* **4** [uncountable] a good reputation; respect from other people http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/honour_1 )

Comment: How old are "his women"? And what is the relationship?  Daughters? Sisters? Wife? Mother?

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example.  What would such a person do if he found that a female relative had, in his estimation, been taken advantage of (sexually or otherwise)? Would he just be "conscious and emotional", or would he feel obliged to DO something?

Comment: [*protective*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/protective) as suggested by @Christopher conveys the sentiment quite well, I feel. A good father and husband is protective of his children, and his wife.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While, as Mr. Lawler has indicated, there doesn’t seem to be a single word in English which specifically means **a male’s awareness of, and emotional concern for, the chastity of his female relatives**, such concerns are by no means wholly absent from the Anglo-speaking cultures I am familiar with.

In America, for example, fathers, uncles, brothers, and even cousins, are normally quite protective of the “***honor***” of their female relatives, and make no mistake, such concerns may include issues of “***chastity***” (*or its absence*) though these are seldom voiced outside the confines of the family.

I believe the words *paternal*, *paternalism*, *paternalistic*, *paternally*, encapsulate, *in a general fashion*, the idea OP seeks to express.

> **Paternal** *adjective*
>
> **1**. of or appropriate to a father:
>
> • ‘*he reasserted his paternal authority*'
>
> **1**.**1**. Showing a kindness and care associated with a father; fatherly:

• ‘*my elders in the newsroom kept a paternal eye on me*'

• ‘*His style with the crews is almost paternal, strong yet fair.*’

> **Origin**
>
> Late Middle English: from late Latin *paternalis*, from Latin *paternus* 'fatherly, belonging to a father', from *pater* 'father'. See, Oxford Dictionaries [**paternal**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/paternal)
>
> **Paternalism** *noun*
>
> The policy or practice on the part of people in positions of authority of restricting the freedom and responsibilities of those subordinate to them in the subordinates' supposed best interest.

• ‘*Even when his children were fully grown, he felt an abiding sense of protective and benevolent paternalism whenever he thought of them.*’

***Disclaimer***: *based on some commentary I've seen I'd like to make it clear that I am merely answering an OP and not making an endorsement or expressing personal value judgments on particular manifestations of "paternalism." Like many other emotions and ideals, and the actions they can engender, paternalism, like maternalism, can be appropriate, protective and enhancing and, on the other hand, can also be excessive, intrusive, and incredibly damaging.*

Comment: This is more cultural than linguistic.  While the attitude exists, it's certainly far from the norm for the whole country.  It's often rooted more in practical concerns about health, safety, and avoidance of unwanted pregnancies, than in 'honor'.   Nor would I, as a fairly mainstream American, think that 'paternal' describes this attitude.  Most people would, I think, see it as at least vaguely unhealthy (which is why there's no exact translation), and in the extreme, might well suspect child abuse.

Comment: @jamesqf - well you have an interesting "take" on the issue of "paternalism" and though I appreciate your taking the time to comment your judgments are your own and obviously not mine. Moreover, regardless of how you feel about my answer this concept (paternalism) is as close as I could get to an English language word which approaches the sense OP seeks. That anyone would equate paternal instincts with child abuse is disquieting and, I think,  evidence of some form of ignorance and/or dissociation.

Comment: I agree with Eva. "Such concerns are by no means absent from the Anglo-speaking cultures". I hope we will come up with some more Research about it

Comment: I think you're being over-sensitive based on a single comment. I too disagree with jamesqf conclusion, maybe he is thinking of *patriarch*  which does tend to carry negative connotations. I consider both *paternal* and *maternal*  to be very positive words.

Comment: Thanks for checking-up on me Sis, I'm OK, and no, @Mari-Lou, I'm not being overly sensitive. My disclaimer is not based solely on the comment you mention but rather on the whole gestalt of this issue, including some links below the OP concerning "*honour-killing*" etc. I'm a committed feminist and don't wish to be misunderstood on what I consider an important issue. I, too, recognize positive/negative manifestations of  paternal/maternal behavior.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

In the narrow sense “Ghairat” means 'jealousy', namely [male sexual jealousy](https://www.google.com/search?q=sexual%20jealousy&oq=sexual%20jealousy&aqs=chrome..69i57.43447254j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=male%20sexual%20jealousy&revid=2137521445). Peter van Sommers says of 'jealousy': “envy concerns what you would like to have but don’t possess, whereas jealousy concerns what you have and do not wish to lose.”

[Jealously](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/jealousy): `mental uneasiness from suspicion or fear of rivalry, unfaithfulness, etc., as in love or aims; vigilance in maintaining or guarding something.` (dictionary.reference.com).

In the broad sense “Ghairat” means (as Little Eva hinted at) '[sense of honor](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sense+of+honor)', namely '[manly honor](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2012/10/01/manly-honor-part-i-what-is-honor/)' ( I hope I am not coming through as sexist because am definitely not).

[Honor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/honor) (thefreedictionary.com):

a. `A sense of principled uprightness of character; personal integrity:` `conducted herself with honor; saw the challenge as a matter of honor.`

b. `A code of integrity, dignity, and pride, chiefly among men, that was maintained in some societies, as in feudal Europe, by force of arms.`

```
c. A woman's chastity or reputation for chastity.
```

But I do agree that the linguistic term Ghairat can only be defined culturally.

Answer (score 1):

Since this does seem to be a question about Arabic, it might be an idea to look up ghayra غيرة in an Arabic-English dictionary. Wehr/Cowan offers these choices: “jealousy; zeal, fervor, earnest concern, vigilant care, solicitude; sense of honor, self-respect”.

I do not think you will find a single English word that covers all these nuances.

Answer (score 0):

Pudency or pudor is the word for ghairat in English

Comment: Mind quoting a dictionary? And are you sure these words are (a) in modern use and (b) describe *a man who is concerned with* modesty, and not just *modesty* itself?

Comment: *Pudency* is marked as "literary" in Oxford Dictionaries Online, so is not a good option. *Pudor* is not listed there.